# STM32F446 Booting

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller, boot, firmware

The arm.developer.com states that "At Reset, Cortex-M3 and Cortex-M4 processors always boot from a vector table at address zero". How is it possible that f.e. STM32F446 has the vector table located at 0x0800 0000 address? I know about VTOR, but it doesnt seem that it is used there to do that.

### [image]

Is there any bootloader thath changes the VTOR, basing on the BOOT pins of MCU?

Comment: it says aliased right there on that page.

Comment: The logic if-then-elses the transaction to a specific bus/part (one or another flash or an sram) in the system (it does not really change the address, just picks a bus) based on inputs, not from arm, into the (arm bus) address decoder.

Comment: nothing is actually at address zero (not that anything is ACTUALLY at 0x08000000 either).

Answer (score 4):

actually, in stm32f466 you can boot from different types of memories, refer to `page 61`, under section `2.3 Boot configuration`, they stated that:

> The Cortex®-M4 with FPU CPU always fetches the reset vector on the
> ICode bus, which implies to have the boot area available only in the
> code area (typically, Flash memory). STM32F446xx microcontrollers
> implement a special mechanism to be able to boot from other memories
> (like the internal SRAM).
>
> In the STM32F446xx, three different boot modes can be selected through
> the BOOT[1:0] pins as shown in Table 2.

[image]

so botting from which memory actually depends on pin states of `BOOT1` and `BOOT0` pins (many people when making a board layout forget to connect `BOOT0` to `GND` or `VDD`)

then if you continued reading, you will reach section `Physical remap in STM32F446xx` as they said:

> Once the boot pins are selected, the application software can modify
> the memory accessible in the code area (in this way the code can be
> executed through the ICode bus in place of the System bus). This
> modification is performed by programming the Section 8.2.1: SYSCFG
> memory remap register (SYSCFG_MEMRMP) in the SYSCFG controller.
>
> The following memories can thus be remapped:
>
>  Main Flash memory
>
>  System memory
>
>  Embedded SRAM1 (112 KB)
>
>  FMC bank 1 (NOR/PSRAM 1 and 2)
>
>  FMC SDRAM bank 1

so the whole idea revolves around the ability of `stm32f466` to remap an address (like `0x0800 0000` which is the base address of embedded flash memory) to the address (`0x0000 0000`) based on your configurations.

and if you go to `SYSCFG memory remap register (SYSCFG_MEMRMP)` in `page 196`, you will find that they stated:

> **Bits 2:0 MEM_MODE**: Memory mapping selection Set and cleared by
> software. This bit controls the memory internal mapping at address
> 0x0000 0000. After reset these bits take the value selected by the
> Boot pins (except for FMC).
>
> 000: Main Flash memory mapped at 0x0000 0000
>
> 001: System Flash memory mapped at 0x0000 0000
>
> 010: FMC Bank1 (NOR/PSRAM 1 and 2) mapped at 0x0000 0000
>
> 011: Embedded SRAM (SRAM1) mapped at 0x0000 0000
>
> 100: FMC/SDRAM Bank 1 mapped at 0x0000 0000

Comment: I guess your answer wasn't chosen as selected because it went into (correct) technical detail without giving a short clear answer first, so I will add a TLDR: upon normal boot, the very same Flash is mapped to 0x00000000 and 0x08000000 at the same time. Addresses 0x00000004 and 0x08000004 point to the very same physical memory in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

ST simply purchased an ARM IP from arm and put it in their chip (it is an "ST" chip not an "ARM" chip, arm does not generally make chips, this helps with the understanding that arm is just IP purchased for this chip, that incidentally can be relatively easily swapped out for a mips or risc-v and still have the same address space, etc, just recompile your code).

VTOR is part of the ARM IP and technically if you read the real stuff from arm and not the bad stuff and/or chip vendor.  VTOR resets to the values placed on strap or input pins to the arm core, the chip vendor pics VTOR and it probably has a default of zero when the chip vendor purchases that ip but they can put a different address or put logic in front of it for runtime changes (and possibly angering an army of software developers).

It is possible but unlikely (can easily test this yes?) that st actually changes the inputs to the core, but instead at the end of the arm bus which is the end of arm in this chip.  The logic that is decoding upper bits to decided where to send this transaction, can also and does have other inputs to that decision.  It is very likely not actually changing the address in the logic to 0x08000000 that would be silly but instead simply sends the transaction down the correct, bus.  As you get further into the chip on layers of buses the upper address bits are ignored and lower address bits are consumed to pick the bus.

Think of an address on mail, country, state, city, zip code, street, street number, person.   Granted zip code can bypass some of these, but it is perfectly possible that each of those sorts in the mail system happen in a different facility.  And if it is a one stoplight town the one postal carrier may know that Tommy is at the Four Leaf Clover Bar on Ruesdays and might just deliver there instead of his house.

Unless there is an error when it gets down to the final zip code post office, the city and state can be ignored.  Street, address and person.

No different in a chip, various factors send things down different buses that lead to more buses that lead to more buses.  Like highways, down to smaller roads down to one house.

And the chip vendor can have features that change the default paths in the same way we can have if-then-elses in our code too.  Display what the user is typing unless it is a password then replace the characters on the way to the display with something else.

Does "ANY" bootloader change VTOR, well if it can be changed (some cores you can't, as the real docs state (ARM ARM, ARM TRM, and the AXI/AHB specs are the real docs, the others can be as bad as they are good to the programmer)) obviously someone has done it for some reason.

Not all mcus need a bootloader and even if they have a bootloader does not mean your application is that complicated.  I would say the typical use case the vector table is determined at link time and no reason to change it runtime.  But if you have an rtos for example and you allow drivers or code to be loaded at runtime, then you may need a solution as the flash is flash and obviously crazy to change it there. So you would point VTOR to sram if you can and then you can control the vector table changes runtime as code or drivers register and deregister themselves.  But you could also link the bulk of the vectors to known addresses in sram, and then those addresses in sram can contain a jump to the registered handler and can be changed runtime without a change to vtor (how you would do it pre-vtor or with cores that do not allow changing of vtor)(well, how I would do it, there are other solutions)...

Yes, obviously, some bootloader, somewhere, has changed VTOR.

Other vendors do this, st and nxp and ti all alias zero to some memory, and use different addresses, even st has two 0x08000000 and 0x00200000 in some chips.  I just looked it up and deleted it.  ti's msp432s are like 0x01000000 and mmm NXP I think I saw 0x10000000, but some others atsamd parts (atmel, now, sigh, microchip) efm32 (silabs), and microbit, umm nordic my code at least uses zero.  But maybe I did not dig deep enough into those parts for those blink the led examples.

So if/as you explore other arm based products (mcus or full sized), you have to look, chip by chip, how all this works.  Get into the full sized Linux capable arm based chips and it gets much more complicated.  Fortunately a lot of the time the work is done for you, put your code on some sd card interface with the SD card prepared a very specific way, and the chip will magically put your code in the on chip sram and boot it and that is one of a dozen ways to get your code in, but may be the way you (and hardware) choose for your product.  How each chip maps axi/ahb addresses into the on chip sram or external dram is specific to that chip vendor and chip family or even specific chip.

When a vendor purchases a processor core (vs when they just use their own, msp430, avr, pic, etc) and that processor core has a hardcoded entry point, it is very likely that the chip vendor is going to alias or window or whatever term you like to allow different boot paths for different use cases or debugging of that device.  (in circuit programming vs normal runtime, debugging vs normal runtime, flash-less designs).  And as a result while there maybe 20 vendors that buy the exact same processor core, there can be 20 or more different ways to deal with that reset entry point.